Change sign of function output depending on sign of input
I am using the function ToPolarCoordinates[{x,y}] here to ask a generic question about changing the sign of one of the output elements of a function, depending on the inputs.
Question:
The function ToPolarCoordinates[{x,y}] converts a vector {x,y} to its polar coordinates {r,theta}.
I wish to apply this function to apply the following if-else pseudocode:
If y > 0, {r,theta} = ToPolarCoordinates[{x,y}]
If y < 0, {r,-theta} = ToPolarCoordinates[{x,y}]

Thus, for negative y, I should get back a negative theta automatically. I would like to apply this in a one-liner, without putting in if-else statements. Can someone please help?

Its implemented in ArcTan with two arguments:

ToPolarCoordinates[{x,y}] just gives the negative angle for negative y. What do you need, precisely?

I am sorry, I just wanted the code to manipulate the outputs for a generic function. The question occurred to me while using ToPolarCoordinates. I will modify the question to state this.

You can use
ToPolar=Function[{x,y} , {#1,Abs[#2]}&@@ToPolarCoordinates[{x,y}]]

NB: Roland F's function is identical to ToPolarCoordinates[{x,y}] and thus is not what you asked.

He say he wants a negative angle for negative y, not yours absolute angle, The notation with -theta on the left in the function  argument looks UnMathematically.

@Roland F I agree, the question itself is unclear. But still, what is the difference between your function ToPolar and ToPolarCoordinates which he seems to reject?

Its implemented in ArcTan with two arguments:
 ToPolar=Function[{x,y} ,  Sqrt[x^2+y^2],   ArcTan[x,y]}]


Sqrt[x^2+y^2^2] is there a typo?
